# Issue with audio for slideshow with Photos

Tags: macos, photos, slideshow

I have a problem when adding music to a slideshow in photos. When I add a piece of music and check the 'fit to music' the timing is never right and I'm left with about a minute of silence at the end of the slideshow.

Alternatively if I try and vary the time of the slideshow manually, it won't let me and resets itself to default time.

Both of these issues mean that I cannot get a piece of music to fit in time with a slideshow, which is proving highly frustrating.

I'm using a new MacBook OS X Yosemite 10.10.5 (14F27)

Comment: How many slides? How long is the song?

Comment: It's May of 2017 and I am having the same problem. I have tried numerous things within the Photos app, but still wind up with no music for the final 10 slides. This seems to be a problem within the app. Wonder why it is still not fixed, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I am having the exact same problem... too much silence at end of slide show, no matter which song or how many songs I use. And no ability to set a manual duration for the slideshow the slider keeps shooting back to 8:52.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not able to reproduce what you are saying. The duration in the top right under export seems responsive. I add the song I want, notice how long it plays and the slide show duration updates.

My guess is you have more than one song queued in the top right under selected music, but it's hard to know without poking around your project.

[image: Photos detail]

<sup>The above is from Version 1.1 (330.21.0)</sup>

Comment: In my example there are 3 songs cued to play. When I export the file, they all fit and work fine, but for some reason there is about a minutes worth of silence at the end. It seems that the music is not syncing correctly, so it finishes before the slideshow.

If I try and add music and then amend the duration of the slideshow automatically the slider reverts back to the original time length of the slideshow. e.g its length is 8:24 and then try and change the time to 10:00 and it keeps reverting back to 8:24.

Answer (score 0):

In my example there are 3 songs cued to play. When I export the file, they all fit and work fine, but for some reason there is about a minutes worth of silence at the end. It seems that the music is not syncing correctly, so it finishes before the slideshow.

If I try and add music and then amend the duration of the slideshow automatically the slider reverts back to the original time length of the slideshow. e.g its length is 8:24 and then try and change the time to 10:00 and it keeps reverting back to 8:24.

Comment: Wow - that's odd. Worst case, you could export the slideshow to a movie and trim it in Quicktime. I wonder if you have some odd track or have exposed some subtle bug. What happens if you do the math on how long the slide show "should" last and set the slide duration appropriately?

Comment: That's what I tried and every time I try and set the slide duration it just reverts back to the original time. I can't adjust it manually after doing the math for the length of time the clip should be.

Comment: I suppose you might have to export all the photos for the slide show and save a copy of the three songs to /Users/Shared - then make a new user account and just import those few items into a clean Photos library and a clean iTunes library with no other user settings changes. You'll know pretty quickly if you've found a bug in the code or your Photos library is the source of the issue.

Comment: Could you add about 8 blank slides at the end of the slideshow?  The music then ends at last important slide?